# Work Day Calendar - Appending 3 DIVs Together Dynamically via JS - Trying to Flush Final DIV to the Right

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, calendar

working on a simple work day calendar for my bootcamp.  95% there - all of the logic works well, but i am having an issue getting the save button to properly float all the way to the right and flush out the DIV with no errant space between the button and the right edge of the block.

here's the github repository for this project:
https://github.com/infiniteoo/homework_week_05_third_party_apis

here's a live example:
https://infiniteoo.github.io/homework_week_05_third_party_apis/

here's the relevant code pertaining to this issue for quicker review:

```
timeDiv.text(finalHour + amPM);
    timeDiv.addClass('time-div');

    // 2nd column: events (big/wide)
    let descriptionDiv = $("<div>");
    let textAreaForDiv = $("<textarea>");
    textAreaForDiv.attr('id', 'textarea' + hour);

    descriptionDiv.append(textAreaForDiv);
    descriptionDiv.addClass("description");
    descriptionDiv.css("width", "80%");
   


    // creates floppy disk icon for save button
    let saveIcon = $('<i>');
    saveIcon.addClass("fa fa-save");

    // 3rd column: save button 
    let saveDiv = $("<div>");
    saveDiv.addClass("saveBtn ");
    saveDiv.attr('id', hour);
 

    // add icon to save button
    saveDiv.append(saveIcon);

    // append all three individual blocks to the bigger div
    timeBlock.append(timeDiv, descriptionDiv, saveDiv);

    timeBlock.addClass("time-block row");

    if (currentHour > hour) {

        // if the hour has passed, make the background grey
        timeBlock.addClass("past");

    } else if (currentHour < hour) {

        // if the hour happens in the future, make the background green
        timeBlock.addClass("future");
        textAreaForDiv.attr("placeholder", "Enter a task to complete this hour...");

    } else {

        // make the background red
        timeBlock.addClass("present");
        textAreaForDiv.attr("placeholder", "Enter a task to complete this hour...");
    }

    // add completed time block to the main container 
    $("#main-contain").append(timeBlock);
```

now, if i wanted to 'cheat' and put some padding-left on the save button, that fixes it, but the website breaks when you view it at a smaller width, and these projects need to be responsive.

i'm sure there's something small i'm missing, and quite honestly if you could rather give me a HINT versus the answer, i would prefer it.  if you do that, i promise i will return to the thread and post the working answer and praise you with glory.

can anyone please point me in the right direction?

thanks so much for your help!

Comment: You are assigning an inline width to one element, I would look at whether all your percentage widths add up to 100%.

Comment: You’re correct that the description div is at 80%.  The only other element that has width assigned to it is the save button but it’s only at 7%.  If it goes any higher it moves the save button to the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using flex on the row element. This will by default put child elements bang up against each other to the left.

You can get them spaced out along the row in various ways. I think the one you want is `space-between` this will divide up any spare space evenly and put it between the elements, with the left most element hard against the left and the rightmost one hard against the right (which is where you want the save button to be). So, add this:

```
.row {
  justify-content: space-between
}
```

Comment: this was the correct answer!  thank you very much!  it's perfect now.  you are the best!